# Sudden PostSharp compilation error on hosted build controller

Tags: tfs, postsharp, azure-devops

As of yesterday, I suddenly get the following error on the hosted build controller:

> unknown: error: Unhandled exception (4.1.10.0, postsharp.4.0-x86.exe,
>   CLR 4.0.30319.394271, Release): Value cannot be null.  unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.CreateInstance(Domain domain,
>   ProjectInvocation projectInvocation)  unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.^63o9P8x3(Domain _0,
>   ProjectInvocationParameters _1)  unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.^63o9P8x3(Domain _0,
>   ProjectConfiguration[] _1, ProjectInvocationParameters _2)  unknown:
>   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.LoadBindingMaps(Project project) 
>   unknown: at ^GdBbaAyAGz1E.^i5Uba8Lq(Project _0)  unknown: at
>   ^GdBbaAyAGz1E.^vTJIU/Al(String _0, String _1, Lazy`1 _2, Lazy`1 _3) 
>   unknown: at ^GdBbaAyAGz1E.^EiKs9kwa(String _0, ^siEGsPw0R2vn _1,
>   ^siEGsPw0R2vn _2)  unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.LoadAssembly(String assemblyLocation,
>   LoadAssemblyOptions options)  unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleReader.ReadModule(ReadModuleStrategy _0) 
>   unknown: at PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleReader.ReadModule()  unknown:
>   at PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleReader.ImportAssemblyManifest() 
>   unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.set_AssemblyManifest(AssemblyManifestDeclaration
>   value)  unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyEnvelope.^TQxYMQQ5(ModuleDeclaration
>   _0)  unknown: at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.NotifyChildPropertyChanged(Element
>   child, String property, Object oldValue, Object newValue)  unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.NamedElementCollection`1.^ntTxzSq/(!0
>   _0, String _1)  unknown: at PostSharp.Sdk.Collections.NonUniqueNameIndex`1.Add(T item)  unknown:
>   at PostSharp.Sdk.Collections.MultiDictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue
>   value)  unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Collections.MultiDictionary`2.InternalTryGetValue(TKey
>   key, Header& header)  unknown: at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue&
>   value)  unknown: at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)  unknown:
>   Parameter name: key  unknown: System.ArgumentNullException: Value
>   cannot be null.  unknown: Parameter name: key See below for details. 
>   unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation
>   projectInvocation)  unknown: at
>   PostSharp.Hosting.Program.ExecuteImpl()

I've never has this before and I can't reproduce it locally.

Has anybody else seen similar issues rise since yesterday? Or does anyone have a hint to a possible solution?

Comment: It seems to be a pre-release of PostSharp 4.1. Please try with the latest PostSharp 4.2, which is backward-compatible with 4.1 and supported.

Comment: I'm experience a similar error with Visual Studio Team Services's Hosted Build Controller as of yesterday. My PostSharp version and stack trace are different: error: Unhandled exception (4.1.26.0, postsharp.4.0-x86.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.394271, Release): Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key See below for details.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
at PostSharp.Sdk.Collections.MultiDictionary`2.InternalTryGetValue(

Comment: Please let me know if you would like the remainder of the stack trace. I don't want to trash the comments.

Comment: We received few reports of similar issues in past few days even for 4.2. Could you please contact us on our technical support after upgrading to PostSharp 4.2 with details about your project? Also let us know if this also happens with on-premises agent (i.e. VSO agent running on machine where your project compiles successfully). Thanks!

Comment: We don't release or own post sharp on the build system.  I assume you are bringing as part of your build?  That stack doesn't mean anything to VSO because it's a stack in PostSharp (external to us that you are bringing) ... However

Comment: We have not rolled a new agent or new service change (that's coming next week).  BUT, what has changed is a .net framework 4.6.1 was added (came with VS QU2) and the azure image is corrupting some binaries.  That's the only thing that I can see that changed.  It only went to the Xaml image and not the build.vnext image yet.  We got a workaround today and we're trying it.  I'm not sure if that's the Post Sharp issue but that's all that changed.

Answer (score 1):

I just create a project with PostSharp 4.2 and build it with Hosted Build Controller, get the same error with you. It seems that something changed in Hosted Build Controller side break this. I have help you submit a feedback on Microsoft Connect Page, refer to this link for details: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2292318

For now, you can use vNext Build System to build your project as a workaround. The build can be finished successfully with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eddie. Is there any way to quickly / (semi-)automatically convert my current builds to the vNext system? Or will I have to manually redefine everything (we're talking 8 builds).

Comment: @Idx There isn't any tool to convert the definitions for now. You need to create them manually.

Comment: The tool to convert most Xaml builds is just "New Definition" and pick the Visual Studio definition.  Pick your solution or msbuild project, build.  That's the equivalent of the in the box Xaml templates.  We've discussed creating a tool but it would just do that.

Comment: We added more diagnostic information to PostSharp. Please update to 4.2.19 and include the build log to the ticket http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/3025-postsharp-breaking-in-vso-continuous-integration-builds-systemargumentnullexception-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-key. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of PostSharp version 4.2.20, my CI VSO hosted build is able to complete succefully.